# Emacs - Symbol's function definition is void: R

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I have installed emacs and ess in MacOSx with below command:

```
sudo port install ess +emacs_app
```

But when I try to run below code block in org mode with C-c C-c:

```
#+begin_src R :results output :session :exports both
summary(mtcars)
#+end_src
```

It return a error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: R
```

But I can run R in shell mode which means R is in my path already, why it still report this error?

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is no Emacs function named `R` that is defined. This likely means that the Emacs library that defines that function has not been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed ess package but you need to load ess library with below command in emacs init file (~/.emacs/init.el):

```
(require 'ess-site)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((R . t)))
```

For more details, refer to [R Source Code Blocks in Org Mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html)